# How to write dynamic text to LED Display over Serial w/ Arduino

Tags: c++, python, arduino

So I think I'm close, but I've hit a wall. Here's what I'm trying to accomplish: I have a program that's counting clicks, and will send Serial data to the Arduino (UNO) anytime the value is updated.

So far I have the following working:
- Scrolling Marquee on the LED Display (from Freetronics - http://www.freetronics.com/products/dot-matrix-display-32x16-red#.UOBeKInjmdM )
- Python script that writes new data to the Arduino over Serial (using PySerial)
- And the Arduino is correctly receiving the data in the Serial Monitor...

SO my issue is I can't get it to write to the LED Display, please help!

Here's my code:

```
import serial
import argparse

myserial = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodemfd121', 9600)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Example with non-optional arguments')

parser.add_argument('count', action="store", type=str)

results = parser.parse_args()

count = results.count
message = "total clicks: " + count

print message

myserial.write(message)
```

Example: `$ python app.py 200` 
This will send "total clicks: 200" to the Arduino

And here's my Arduino Sketch:

```
/*
  Scrolling text demonstration sketch for Freetronics DMD.
 See http://www.freetronics.com/dmd for resources and a getting started guide.
 Note that the DMD library uses the SPI port for the fastest, low overhead writing to the
 display. Keep an eye on conflicts if there are any other devices running from the same
 SPI port, and that the chip select on those devices is correctly set to be inactive
 when the DMD is being written to.  
 */

// you always need the code from here...........
#include <DMD.h> // for DMD
#include <SPI.h> // SPI.h must be included as DMD is written by SPI (the IDE complains otherwise)
#include <TimerOne.h> 
#include "SystemFont5x7.h"
#include "Arial_black_16.h"
#include "Arial_14.h"
#define DISPLAYS_ACROSS 1 // change to 2 for two screens, etc. 
#define DISPLAYS_DOWN 1
DMD dmd(DISPLAYS_ACROSS, DISPLAYS_DOWN); // creates instance of DMD to refer to in sketch

char message[] = "test string to be updated";

char serIn; //var that will hold the bytes in read from the serialBuffer

void ScanDMD() // necessary interrupt handler for refresh scanning of DMD
{ 
  dmd.scanDisplayBySPI();
}

void setup()
{
   //initialize TimerOne's interrupt/CPU usage used to scan and refresh the display
   Timer1.initialize( 5000 );           //period in microseconds to call ScanDMD. Anything longer than 5000 (5ms) and you can see flicker.
   Timer1.attachInterrupt( ScanDMD );   //attach the Timer1 interrupt to ScanDMD which goes to dmd.scanDisplayBySPI()  
   dmd.clearScreen( true );   //true is normal (all pixels off), false is negative (all pixels on)

   Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop()
{

// only if there are bytes in the serial buffer execute the following code
if(Serial.available()) {    
  //keep reading and printing from serial untill there are bytes in the serial buffer
   while (Serial.available()>0){
      serIn = Serial.read();    //read Serial   
       Serial.write( byte(serIn));
   }
   //the serial buffer is over just go to the line (or pass your favorite stop char)               
   Serial.println();
}

   // Now I want to write the Serial message ti the DMD Disply
  dmd.selectFont(Arial_Black_16);

  // the text in the quotes in the next line will be scrolled across the display(s).
  // message writes the TEST message above, but I want it to write serIn variable (serial data)
  dmd.drawMarquee(message,strlen(message),(32*DISPLAYS_ACROSS)-1,0);

  // THIS IS WHAT I WANT, but I get this error "invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'"
  //dmd.drawMarquee(serIn,strlen(serIn),(32*DISPLAYS_ACROSS)-1,0);

  long start=millis();
  long timer=start;
  boolean ret=false;
  while(!ret){
    if ((timer+30) < millis()) {
      ret=dmd.stepMarquee(-1,0);
      timer=millis();
    }
  }     
  delay(100);
}
```

The error I keep running into is that `dmd.drawMarquee()` takes the first parameter as a string, and I don't know anything about C++ so I think I'm messing up the data types.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well that error is because you're passing only a single character, and you need to pass an array of chars (a string). However I think there's more wrong than just that. Your serial comms for example, doesn't look like it'll work.

Comment: Serial comms won't work? Not sure what you mean? Because the code above does print the correct sting in the Arduino Serial monitor. http://cl.ly/image/2A0C0H132M3u

Comment: I'm just wondering what would be expected to happen if the string is only partially received in one loop iteration.

Comment: Should I not be running that in the loop?

Comment: It may be find to have it in the loop, assuming the buffering is ok with the delay loop, but there may be cases where it doesn't do what you expect. But as I don't know what you expect, I'm not sure... I've given a tentative solution for your string handling problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So while I have concerns about how the serial reading is mixed in with the display driving, here's how you might change the serial reading to read as string:

The serial reading part:

```
if(Serial.available()) {    
...
}
```

Is just reading single characters. You need to store those in a buffer instead.

Change:

```
char serIn; //var that will hold the bytes in read from the serialBuffer
```

To:

```
char serIn[40]; //buffer that will hold the bytes in read from the serialBuffer
```

And then the serial loop:

```
if(Serial.available()) {  
    int chars_in = 0;
    //keep reading and printing from serial untill there are bytes in the serial buffer
    while (Serial.available()>0 && chars_in<39){
        serIn[chars_in] = Serial.read();    //read Serial   
        Serial.write( byte(serIn[chars_in]));
        chars_in++;
    }
    serIn[chars_in] = 0;
    //the serial buffer is over just go to the line (or pass your favorite stop char)               
    Serial.println();
}
```